# link is not coming on using with <a> tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, anchor

I am trying to incorporate link into my html using  tag but its not coming clickable. what i am doing wrong?

```html
<div>
  <p id="notsigned_in" style="text-align: center;">Please <a href='"https://one.vistas.com/saml_login/login?ReturnTo=//content/en_us/me/entry.html?concern=" + encodeURIComponent($("#concern").val())'>Sign in</a> if you want to view your employee's contact information</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML - is not javascript. In your case you can use this code:

```
<a href="" id="link">LINK HERE</a> //Just link without href

<script>
   //Adding href to link
  const baseUrl = 'https://one.vistas.com/saml_login/login?ReturnTo=//content/en_us/me/entry.html?concern=';
  document.getElementById('link').href = baseUrl + encodeURIComponent($("#concern").val());
</script>
```

PS. Sorry for vanilla JS in jQuery project, but it simpler for myself, then jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can't insert javascript into html directly like that. You would add this dynamic link after the page loads. Also included here is an event handler to update the link in case that `#concern` value changes

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  updateLink()
  $('#concern').on('input', updateLink)
})

function updateLink() {
  $('#notsigned_in a').attr('href', `https://one.vistas.com/saml_login/login?ReturnTo=//content/en_us/me/entry.html?concern=${encodeURIComponent($("#concern").val())}`);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='concern' value='the concern value' />
<div>
  <p id="notsigned_in" style="text-align: center;">Please
    <a href=''>Sign in</a> if you want to view your employee's contact information</p>
</div>
```

Comment: `p#notsigned_in` there's no need for that `p`

Answer (score 0):

You can't insert js code directly in html tag like you have done above.
**Try this code:**

```js
function onLinkClicked() {
  let concern = encodeURIComponent($("#concern").val());
  let link = "https://one.vistas.com/saml_login/login?ReturnTo=//content/en_us/me/entry.html?concern=" + concern;
  console.log(link);
  location.href = link;
}
```

```css
.centered {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  Concern: <input id="concern" name="concern" value="452112442"> <br />
  <p id="notsigned_in" class="centered">Please
    <a href='javascript:;' onclick="onLinkClicked()">Sign in</a> if you want to view your employee's contact information
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I know this is an example, but we should really stop to use inline attributes like `style` or `on*`. JS and CSS should be in their respective tags or files. Not disseminated around the document in a render-blocking and hard to debug manner.

Comment: That's also not good. `<style>` should go in `<head>` and `<script>` always right before the closing `</body>` tag. And avoid using `onclick` inline JS. As I said.  If you want to write a better runnable snippet, [edit] and use the `<>` icon button.